Power Apps, User can only view and edit their own records within app (Show records that are only for the current user (Logged in))
With Microsoft Power Apps we are developing Leave Tracker application, and we are using EXCEL as backend.
Two doubts,
1) Display the records that are only for the current user (Logged in user):

We are using EXCEL as backend.
We are maintaining excel for user credential, Please find the
screenshot below,



Only the user's there in EXCEL can logged in to the app.
How to display user detail's based on the "EmployeeID" (Logged in
user) ?

2) User can only view and edit their own records (Show records that are only for the current user (Logged in)).

We maintaining separate excel for 'Leave Tracker' with user details.



Currently, all user details are displaying in Power apps.
Once i click the particular cell ("Employee ID"). It redirects to
another screen and displaying it's detail.
In power apps it's displaying like this, PFA Power apps screenshot,



Expectation: How to Show records that are only for the current user
(Logged in)) ?

If you need any more detail for clarification. I will add those.
Thanks in advance!

PowerApps can utilize User() function as well as Office365Users connector. These can return the email address of the logged in user. You can utilize this and add email addresses into your excel data, From there, you can put filter on your gallery such as Filter(Data,UserIDColumn=User().Email
This way users will only be able to see their data and manage it.


You could try Office365Users.MyProfile().Id to get the current user id, though the result would be different from the numbers you're using as EmloyeeID.

Then you could use Filter(MyList, 'Employee Roll Number' = Office365Users.MyProfile().Id) on gallery to only display records which has current logged in user id.


Also instead of Office365Users.MyProfile().Id, you can use User().Email to achieve similar results, it would be easier to read an maintain.
